Is there a way to convert an online svg to a png using javascript only?
I am developing a discord bot in using discordjs where it uses this api to return an svg file but I need a png file for the rest of the code. Is there any way to convert this into a png without having to download/save any files?
I tried to use a few different apis and packages but they either didn't work right or were outdated.
(I am not able to use html, css, etc. only javascript and cannot download files)
Edit:
When using api, it returns an svg like this: https://math.vercel.app/?bgcolor=auto&from=%5Ctext%7BEdit%20this%7D%5C%20%5CLaTeX.svg
I have to use this svg and convert it into png only using node (no browser/html/etc.)

This question is similar to: Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. You won't be able to fetch any external SVG due to CORS access restrictions.

@herrstrietzel: I think the question is about doing it in Node.

@Ry: My bad you're probably right. However we definitely need more details and the description should clarify the settings - for instance the link to the math.api isn't directly related to SVG processing.

Yes it is possible with Canvas


function convertSVGtoPNG() {
    var svgElement = document.getElementById('svgElement');
    var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
    var svgBlob = new Blob([svgData], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasElement');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var pngData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var pngImage = document.getElementById('pngImage');
        pngImage.src = pngData;
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
}
.svg-to-png {
  display: flex;
  gap:15px;
}
    <div class="svg-to-png">
      <canvas id="canvasElement" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"></canvas>
      <svg id="svgElement" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange"/>
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="50" fill="green"/>
        <text x="25" y="28" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
    </svg>
      <div>
        <button onclick="convertSVGtoPNG()">SVG to PNG</button> 
      </div>

      <div><img id="pngImage" /></div>
    </div>




Since OP is strictly using NodeJS and no web interfaces, they can use the buffer of the canvas for sending through discord.js

@Elitezen you are absolutely right: Serialize SVG, make blob, draw using canvas, and then canvas to buffer. I did not realized it from the beginning, until you made me. Thank you.
